# PhoneGap+Cordova app is not working on AVD(Android Virtual Device)

Tags: android, cordova

I followed all the steps in the basic Phonegap tutorial (Eclipse, Android SDK, ADT Phonegap),

> Step1: I created an HMTL page in the assets/www folder, ran it, and it
>   showed my hello world html.
>
> Step 2: I added a reference to jQuery Mobile on a CDN in my HTML page:
>   it worked.
>
> Step 3: I edit index.html page, copy-pasted the code, which is a
>   sample from the Phonegap site, and it does... nothing. Not even an
>   alert (I added some alerts to see if something happens, but even the
>   onDeviceReady event doesn't fire.

I have the Phonegap JAR in place, the cordova-1.7.0.js in my assest/www directory, but something is probably missing.

I also tried for Cordova JAR in libs folder, but it is not working.

Can someone help me out?

I also tried another sample from the Phonegap site (the 'device properties', 'Accelerometer' sample code), but it still doesn't work.

It's a fresh Eclipse ADT(Android Development Tool), I've install the Android version to 4.0.3, 4.1.2, 4.2 from Android SDK and I'm using Phonegap 2.2.0.

Answer (score 2):

you need to put this xml file in www folder "config.xml"

here link for xml
https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

Comment: I am getting same error:
1) (14) cannot open file at line 30176 of [00bb9c9ce4]
2) (14) os_unix.c:30176: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) - 
3) Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'exec' at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.2.0.js:984

Answer (score 0):

Check the phonegap.js file resource. you add the script element in the head element. you must the correct cordova-1.7.0.js

Comment: In my project there is JS file in:
myFirstApp/assets/www/cordova-2.2.0.js

and i include it by this resource **src="cordova-2.2.0.js"**